# HP Smart Array E200i controller

Tags: raid, hp, hp-smart-array

Can HP Smart Array E200i 128MB RAID controller wotk without Posted-Write Cache moduler? It's battery have finished its life.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the controller will continue to work... It will just have poor write performance. You should look to replace the battery, though. They are still available.

Comment: And what about reading data? Poor performance also?

Comment: Reading will be okay... You can set the controller to cache reads. THe battery is only useful to protect and buffer writes.

Comment: So, I can remove cach module with battery from RAID controller and controller stil work?

Comment: Yes. You can remove the battery, but leave the cache.